# Call a table using a dynamic identifier

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to call a table in Power Query M dynamically. I have created a simple query below to explain what I am trying to do.

I'd like the result to be "It Worked" as opposed to "Source1" which is what I currently get.

```
let
  Source1 =  Table.FromList(
    {
      [Word1="It",Word2="Worked"]
    },
    Record.FieldValues,
    {"Word1","Word2"}
  ),
  Source2 = "Source" & "1"
in
  Source2
```

**Use Case Details:**

I am trying to do this so that I can call a query based on conditions. such as:

```
if ENV = "production" then
  Customer_s
else
  Customer_m
```

Where `Customer_s` is a query to retrieve customer data found in a CSV file and `Customer_m` is a query to retrive customer data found on a SQL Server.

Because I will be doing this with many tables (not just customer) I thought I'd create a function where you can pass in the model name (ie "Customer") and it would then string it together to call the query.

I just find that PowerBI grinds to a halt and constantly reruns queries unnecessarily which is killing my PC and network speed. I thought an easy way around this would be to create dummy data that looks like the result of SQL Server but is stored locally on my machine. That way I can also write queries if I don't have access to the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have used the terminology correct in this. Hopefully the answer will allow me to also dynamically call the result of another query aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this:

```
= Expression.Evaluate("Source"&"1", #shared)
```

you can dynamically reference other queries. But not other steps in the same query (as it seems). So it has to sit in a new query.

Or was your question about:

```
 Text.Combine({"It", "Worked"}, " ")
```

?

Answer (score 2):

#shared contains a list of all of the available queries and library functions, so you can do something like this:
`Record.Field(#shared, "It " & "Worked")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can't reference anything in the Source1 query because it could represent the result of a much larger query with thousands of rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this work thanks to the information provided by @ImkeF.

I first had to split the two queries so Source1 was evaluated with it's full `let` `in` expression and could then be accessible through `#shared`.

**QUERY 1**

```
let
  Source1 =  Table.FromList(
    {
      [Word1="It",Word2="Worked"]
    },
    Record.FieldValues,
    {"Word1","Word2"}
  )
in
  Source1
```

**Query 2**

```
let
    Source2 = Expression.Evaluate("Source"&"1", #shared)
in
    Source2
```

This has QUERY 2 resulting in:

```
╔═══════╦════════╗
║ Word1 ║ Word2  ║
╠═══════╬════════╣
║ It    ║ Worked ║
╚═══════╩════════╝
```

Thanks @ImkeF and @Alejandro for your assistance.

Comment: I've applied this to my PowerBi and works great ... until....  `Formula.Firewall: Query 'Customer'` bug. ARGH!

Comment: Only way I know how to overcome this is to enable fast combine: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Privacy-levels-Power-Query-CC3EDE4D-359E-4B28-BC72-9BEE7900B540 but this will disable the privacy levels set in your query (if there are any)